# How to get the key of a triggered Geo-Fire Query

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-geofence, geofire

I am building an app that allows a user to trigger a Geo-graphical area, for example driving into the perimeter of particular farms.

I originally was using Geo-fencing API, which works, but also doesn't work so well when the location accuracy dips.

and I liked the idea of Geo-fire as it works if the user's location enter a designated area even if their location accuracy isn't totally accurate, and seems to work a lot faster than Geo-fencing API

anyways, I have a problem with how to determine what Geo-location have I entered, for instance with Geo-fencing API, it tells me which Geo-fence was triggered. where as Geo-fire I have only gotten it to send me a notification once I have triggered it.

#### here is the geo-locations that are in a class

```java
public static final HashMap<String, Map.Entry<LatLng, Integer>> MAIN_GEOFENCES = new HashMap<>();
    static {
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("Ticket Office",new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(new LatLng(-33.911024, 19.119688),GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS_SMALL));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("Maison", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(Maison,GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS_SMALL));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("R45", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(new LatLng(-33.890257, 19.087895),GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS_SMALL));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("Mont Rochelle", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(MontRochelle,150));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("Holden Manz",new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(HoldenManz,GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS_SMALL));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("TurnOffAtRobertsvlei", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(new LatLng(-33.918157, 19.120557),GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS_SMALL));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("ExcelsiorRoad", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(new LatLng(-33.926339, 19.120064),GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS_SMALL));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("Charmonix", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(Charmonix,130));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("DieuDonne", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(DieuDonne,120));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("Grande Provance Platform", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(GrandeProvancePlatform,30));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("Grande Provance Wine", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(GrandProvanceWine,70));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("Grande Provance Resturant", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(GrandProvanceResturant,100));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("Rickety Bridge",new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(RicketyBridge,120));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("Rickety Bridge Platform",new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(RicketyBridgePlatform,30));
            MAIN_GEOFENCES.put("PlatformA", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LatLng, Integer>(PlatformA,30));
    }
```

#### And here is the Geo-Query

```java
 private void GeoFence()
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<LatLng,Integer>> entry : Constants.MAIN_GEOFENCES.entrySet()) {
            GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(entry.getValue().getKey().latitude,entry.getValue().getKey().longitude),0.5f);
            geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    TriggeredGeoFence(String.format("Key %s entered the search area at [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
                    System.out.println(String.format("Key %s entered the search area at [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                    TriggeredGeoFence("Exited");
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

#### Output of the "Entered" trigger

this tells me, my Unique key that is generated and the Coordinates of where I triggered the geo-location

```
I/System.out: Key cDkrRkdTvBaJwnICeVmqtCvHDn92 entered the search area at [-33.911080,19.119722]
```

Please let me know if this is at all possible to do with Geo-fire 
or some direction on where to go and get answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any default method that provides for which location geoquery triggered. But in your case you can find triggered location in this way:

```
private void GeoFence()
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<LatLng,Integer>> entry : Constants.MAIN_GEOFENCES.entrySet()) {
            setGeoQuery(entry);
        }

    }

    private void setGeoQuery(Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<LatLng,Integer>> entry){
        GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(entry.getValue().getKey().latitude,entry.getValue().getKey().longitude),0.5f);
        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                Log.e("triggered for "+entry.getKey(),"lat:"+entry.getValue().getKey().latitude+",lng:"+entry.getValue().getKey().longitude);
                TriggeredGeoFence(String.format("Key %s entered the search area at [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
                System.out.println(String.format("Key %s entered the search area at [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                TriggeredGeoFence("Exited");
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {
             Log.e("triggered for "+entry.getKey(),"lat:"+entry.getValue().getKey().latitude+",lng:"+entry.getValue().getKey().longitude);
            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This code outputs all the geofences as triggered, I only need the geofence that the user has entered and not the whole hashmap as triggered

Comment: I actually got it to work, with a slight modification to your code @Silversky Technology

the modification is just taking the log.e Line that you added and just add that to my original code above my Log messages and it will work great.

Thanks Man you are a hero